# Showing multiple iterations of form fields when in edit file of scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First, I have a model called `Answers` for my trivia game. It stores the multiple possible answers there are to each trivia question (a quiz `has_many` answers). I created a form via scaffold to make an easy UI for submitting a question with a set of four answers.

I want to do this from one form. When the user currently hits submit, I can post all four answers -- each with a different `answer_id` but sharing the same `question_id` (so I can associate 4 answers with one question) -- successfully, like so:

```
 <%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
   <% if @question.errors.any? %>
   <div id="error_explanation">
       <h2><%= pluralize(@question.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this question from being saved:</h2>

     <ul>
        <% @question.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
           <li><%= msg %></li>
           <% end %>
      </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :question_text %><br>
         <%= f.text_field :question_text, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
   <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :category_id %><br>
   <%= f.number_field :category_id, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
</div>
 <h2>Answer Options</h2>
     <%= f.fields_for :answers do |answer| %>
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="answers">
        <div class="field">
         <%= answer.label :answer_1 %><br>
          <%= answer.text_field :answer_text, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
   <%= f.fields_for :answers do |answer| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="answers">
        <div class="field">
         <%= answer.label :answer_2 %><br>
          <%= answer.text_field :answer_text, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
      <%= f.fields_for :answers do |answer| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="answers">
        <div class="field">
         <%= answer.label :answer_3 %><br>
          <%= answer.text_field :answer_text, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
      <%= f.fields_for :answers do |answer| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="answers">
        <div class="field">
         <%= answer.label :answer_4 %><br>
          <%= answer.text_field :answer_text, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
```

If I check in console, it works! I have four different answers (so they are four rows in the table but with the same `question_id`. What is weird is if I then use the edit route, instead of populating four inputs (like `new` does), it shows 16 `text_field` inputs for Answers (labeled Answer 1, Answer 2, Answer 3, Answer 4, Answer 1).

Finally, the other reason I think there could be an issue would be how I am updating the nested `Answers` attribute through the controller, like so:

```
def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:question_text, :category_id, :correct_answer, :answers_attributes => [:id, :answer_text])
 end
```

Am I setting this up incorrectly, such that it would iterate 4x when showing in the Edit file?

Comment: can you post your entire **form_for** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do little different while rendering the form for `edit` action:

You can try something like this:

```
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
  <% if @question.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
     <h2><%= pluralize(@question.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this question from being saved:</h2>
     <ul>
      <% @question.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
         <li><%= msg %></li>
         <% end %>
    </ul>
   </div>
 <% end %>

 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
 </div>

  <% unless @question.new_record? %>
   <% @question.answers.each_with_index do |ans,i| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :answers, ans do |answer| %>
        <%= answer.label "answer_#{i+1}" %><br>
        <%= answer.text_field :answer_text, class: "form-control" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
 <% else %>

  <h2>Answer Options</h2>
  <%= f.fields_for :answers, Answer.new do |answer| %>
      <%= answer.label :answer_1 %><br>
      <%= answer.text_field :answer_text, class: "form-control" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :answers,Answer.new do |answer| %>
      <%= answer.label :answer_2 %><br>
      <%= answer.text_field :answer_text, class: "form-control" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :answers,Answer.new do |answer| %>
       <%= answer.label :answer_3 %><br>
       <%= answer.text_field :answer_text, class: "form-control" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :answers,Answer.new do |answer| %>
       <%= answer.label :answer_4 %><br>
       <%= answer.text_field :answer_text, class: "form-control" %>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
 <%= f.submit @question.new_record? ? "Add" : "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This answer works perfectly. Thanks for laying this out.